# Missing "Export Template" option in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, templates, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to learn & create **Visual Studio templates** and as per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx),

> The simplest type of template to
>   create is an item template. To do so,
>   simply open a project that includes
>   the file you want to use as a template
>   and then chooses File | Export
>   Template to run the Export Template
>   Wizard

Now, **the problem** is that the **"Export Template" option is missing** in my Visual Studio 2005. The version I'm using is **VS 2005 team suite** and the project template I opened to export is **"ASP.NET Web Application**".

Is there any patch to be installed or any setting to be done to get the Export Template option? Or am I not following the right way to create Templates?

Links/leads to good articles/resources on the Internet on VS Templates also would help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "**Tools / Customize / Commands" options** in Visual Studio.

The command you are looking for should be the **File group**, so just drag it from the Customize dialog onto the File pull-down menu.

[alt text http://www.xmlx.net/software/images/vs2005customizemenu.gif](http://www.xmlx.net/software/images/vs2005customizemenu.gif)

*I hope this helps!*